Pure states in the $C^*$-algebra of compact operators
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. I know the pure states of $B(H)$ whenever $H$ is finite-dimensional. They are the vector states $W_x$, i.e., of the form $W_x(A)=\langle Ax,x \rangle$, where $A\in B(H)$. Is the same statement true for $B(H)$ whenever $H$ is infinite-dimensional? Or, at least for $K(H)$, where $K(H)$ is the space of all compact operators in $B(H)$. Any proof or reference will be of much help.

This is true for $K(H)$. See Example 5.1.1 in Murphy’s “$C^\ast$-algebras and operator theory”. It is not true for $B(H)$. Consider the following counterexample: let $A \subset B(H)$ be the subalgebra of diagonal operators $(a_i)$ s.t. $a_i$ converges as $i \to \infty$. Then $\varphi: A \to \mathbb{C}$, $\varphi((a_i)) = \lim_i a_i$ is a character and thus pure state on $A$, whence it can be extended to a pure state on $B(H)$. It is easy to observe that $\varphi$ cannot be induced by any unit vector $x \in H$ on $A$, whence the extended pure state on $B(H)$ is not a vector state either.
